# How can I search a range of lines in python?

Tags: python, regex, sed

I would like to search through a range of lines in a date ordered log file between two dates.  If I were at the command line, `sed` would come handy with:

```
sed -rn '/03.Nov.2012/,/12.Oct.2013/s/search key/search key/p' my.log
```

The above would only display lines between the 3 November, 2012 and 12 of October, 2013 that contain the string "`search key`".

***Is there a light weight way I can do this in `python`?***

I could build a single RE for the above , but it would be nightmarish.

The best  I can come up with is this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

start_date = "03/Nov/2012"
end_date = "12/Oct/2013"

start = False

try:
    with open("my.log",'r') as log:
        for line in log:
            if start:
                if end_date in line:
                    break
            else:
                if start_date in line:
                    start = True
                else:
                    continue
            if search_key in line:
                print line

except IOError, e:
    print '<p>Log file not found.'
```

But this strikes me as not 'pythonic'.

One can assume that search date limits will be found in the log file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `itertools` and a generator is one way:

```
from itertools import takewhile, dropwhile

with open('logfile') as fin:
    start = dropwhile(lambda L: '03.Nov.2012' not in L, fin)
    until = takewhile(lambda L: '12.Oct.2013' not in L, start)
    query = (line for line in until if 'search string' in line)
    for line in query:
        pass # do something
```

Comment: I was just writing a `dropwhile` solution, but you beat me to it.

Comment: Different question perhaps, but how can I turn those `lambda` expressions into boolean regular expression matches?

Comment: @Jamie you'd just have `lambda L: re.search(r'03\.Nov\.2012', L)` which'll result in either `None` for no match or a `MatchObject`

Comment: Actually, your solution does what my `python` hack does, not what the `sed` expression does; is there a simple way to include up to the end of the date string in the `takewhile()` instead of ommiting everything after the first occurence.

Comment: So just test for `None`; got it.

Comment: @Jamie well `None` is falsey in a boolean sense, and a `MatchObject` truthy... so just the result of search is fine - it doesn't need to be compared to anything